AWS CDK error TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks
I have a infrastructure file to deploy the resources to AWS using python's aws-cdk.
Here is my psuedo code
cpu_utilization_alarm = cloudwatch.Alarm(self, 'CPUUtilizationAlarm',
   # other config
)

cpu_utilization_alarm.add_alarm_action(cloudwatch_actions.SnsAction(cloudwatch_alert_sns_topic))

Upon running this deployment aws-cdk from typeguard throws error as:
TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks, and is always failing at cpu_utilization_alarm.add_alarm_action
I tried the following things until now:

Comment the line to debug, the code runs without any issue
Make the parameter as tuple like cpu_utilization_alarm.add_alarm_action(cloudwatch_actions.SnsAction(cloudwatch_alert_sns_topic),)
Tried to use @typeguard_ignore
Initialize cloudwatch_actions.SnsAction(cloudwatch_alert_sns_topic) to a variable then pass as paramter.

server (and local) configuration:

python3.12
aws-cdk 2.151.0

Iam not sure, what am I missing, is it the configuration or typing or typeguard prevent me. Let me know if anymore information is required.
Here is the traceback for error
    cpu_utilization_alarm.add_alarm_action(cloudwatch_actions.SnsAction(cloudwatch_alert_sns_topic))
  File "python3.12/site-packages/aws_cdk/aws_cloudwatch/__init__.py", line 14809, in add_alarm_action
    check_type(argname="argument actions", value=actions, expected_type=typing.Tuple[type_hints["actions"], ...]) # pyright: ignore [reportGeneralTypeIssues]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "python3.12/site-packages/typeguard/__init__.py", line 759, in check_type
    checker_func(argname, value, expected_type, memo)
  File "python3.12/site-packages/typeguard/__init__.py", line 497, in check_tuple
    if not isinstance(value, expected_type):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/typing.py", line 1213, in __instancecheck__
    return self.__subclasscheck__(type(obj))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/typing.py", line 1216, in __subclasscheck__
    raise TypeError("Subscripted generics cannot be used with"
TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks


Adding a @typeguard.suppress_type_checks decorator on the function or class should work.

I found it somewhere to shut the checks, but its been introduced in 3.0.0 and aws-cdk==2.151.0 required max 2.13.3 version. Any other way to fix with 2.13.3 version?

Are you saying you can't install the latest version of typeguard with AWS CDK 2.151.0? I don't believe that AWS CDK requires typeguard at all - can you clarify? What's the error?

There are 2 parts of the error, I added the traceback in question:

Typeguard throws error upon checking the cloudwatch_alert_sns_topic
aws-cdk==2.151.0 supports typeguard ~=2.13.3, here a supporting doc https://libraries.io/pypi/aws-cdk-lib/2.151.0/tree. So Iam facing conflicts on upgrading typeguard. And @typeguard.suppress_type_checks is being introduced in typeguard==3.0.0, supporting doc https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/versionhistory.html


Oh, I was indeed wrong about AWS CDK not requiring typeguard - thanks for the link

No problem. I found the workaround as well, added in the answers below. Thanks for the help though!

I figured out the solution, I need to add export PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1 to enable -O flag which disables __debug__ and bypass the pylint checks
